# Javascript HTML how to remove a Div Element duplicated by an onClick event

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble deleting an element which was duplicated by an onClick event.

*Firstly, please don't rage at my IDs....the page is a mess right now.*

I have a div element that appears after a radio button is selected.
The Radio Buttons I have created:

```
<div class="wrapper">

            <input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="select" id="option-1">
            <input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="select" id="option-2" checked>
            <label for="option-1" class="option option-1"><span>Yes</span></label>
            <label for="option-2" class="option option-2"><span>No</span></label>
        </div>
```

In this div element is a form.

```
<div class="basicInfoContainer">
            <div class="basicInfoItemTitle"><h3>Full Name</h3></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItem"><input type="text" id="fNames" name="Full Names" placeholder="John Doe" size="50"></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItemTitle"><h3>Site Name</h3></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItem"><input type="text" id="sName" name="Site Name" placeholder="ABC" size="50"></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItemTitle"><h3>Site Address</h3></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItem"><input type="text" id="sAddress" name="Site Address" placeholder="123 Story Street" size="50"></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItemTitle"><h3>Branch</h3></div>
            <div class="basicInfoItem">
                <select name="Branch" id="branch" aria-placeholder="Select a Branch">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Branch...</option>
                <option value="Pretoria">Option1</option>
                <option value="Midrand">Option2</option>
                </select></div>
        </div>

<button class="addItem" value="Add Item" id="addItem" onclick = "duplicate()" style="display: none;"><label for="addItem">Add Item</label></button>
```

This form shows once I press the **Yes** radio button:

```
function yesnoCheck() {
                if (document.getElementById("option-1").checked) {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById("addItem").style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById("addItem").style.display = "none";
                    }
                };
```

I then duplicate the form using:

```
var i = 0;
        var original = document.getElementById('ifYes');
        
        function duplicate() {
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
            clone.id = "ifYes" + ++i;
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);   
        }
```

My question is, when I press **No** On the Radio Buttons, I want all those duplicated div elements to be removed.
Right now, only the one ,coded in the HTML gets removed. Not the elements created by JS.

Comment: Basically, give all the elements you want to (maybe) remove some kind of attribute. Can be, for example, a class. Then use `document.querySelectorAll('.name_of_class')` and remove each match

Comment: I tried that, but I see that it doesn't work if I am trying to remove dynamically created elements. It seems I can remove DOM elements like this.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix it.

The altered code lies below:

```
function yesnoCheck() {
                if (document.getElementById("option-1").checked) {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById("addItem").style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById("addItem").style.display = "none";
                };
                if(document.getElementById("option-2").checked){
                    
                    var removeEquipment= document.getElementById("ifYes0");
                        removeEquipment.remove();
                }
            }

function duplicate() {
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
            clone.id = "ifYes" + i;
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
            
        }
```

By no means efficient, but I got around it by not adding var i up the whole time. Once I press "Add Item", each time it will clone the div element with ID ifYes0.

Then I made a var for ifYes0 and then it removes all additional ones.

I don't care about data retention in those forms that are deleted, but if I need to, in future I might just set those display to none, instead.

Comment: Just a side note. If I clicked on Add Item multiple times, I would need to click on the No radio button multiple times to remove all of the cloned forms. 

To get around this I replaced the if statement with a do while statement.